# why Commands are not executed with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, shell, command

i hev problem with CreatProcess function introduced in windows.h header for c++.
whenever i try to pass it a TCHAR variable containing a cmd command it returns error : CreateProcess failed (2) .
and for this am waiting for your explanations and solutions.

consider code below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

if( argc != 2 )
{
    printf("Usage: %s [cmdline]\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}

// Start the child process.
if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    argv[1],        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
)
{
    printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    return 0;
}

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

// Close process and thread handles.
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

}

notice:when i launch an application with specifying its path ..it works fine like=> "c:\code.exe";

Comment: In which case your application is not working ? You are saying that : code.exe C:\Code.exe is working ?

Comment: in case you pass a DOS command as an argument

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a command `DOS`, you have to run the shell `cmd` before.

`CreateProcess` doesn't do that for you.

The option `/c` of `cmd` permits to run a command in the shell and terminate. You just have to build a command line of the type `cmd /c <your command here>`.

I compiled your code on VS2012 and I tried : `test.exe "cmd /c dir"` and it works like a charm.

From the Microsoft documentation :

> To run a batch file (or a batch command), you must start the command interpreter; set lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a command implemented by the command shell aka `cmd.exe`, you need to actually run cmd.exe. `CreateProcess` doesn't automatically do that for you.

Build a command line of the form `cmd.exe /c <your command here>`. `/c` means "run one command, then terminate".